# python3.7でTypeError: an integer is requiredが解決しません

Tags: python, python3

標準平均をシミュレーションするプログラムを試作しようとして以下のコードを書きました。

```
#数値計算
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

#グラフの描写
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

%matplotlib inline

#標本平均を何度も計算する関数

def calc_sample_mean(size,n_trial):
    sample_mean_array=np.zeros(n_trial)
    for i in range(0,n_trial):
        sample=population.rvs(size==size)
        sample_mean_array[i]=sp.mean(sample)
    return(sample_mean_array)

#データを10個選んで標本平均を作る、10000回繰り返す

np.random.seed(1)
size_10=calc_sample_mean(size=10,n_trial=10000)
size_10_df=pd.DataFrame({
    "sample_mean":size_10,
    "size":np.tile("size 10",10000)
})
```

引数の指定は間違っていないと思いますが、以下のようなエラーメッセージが出ます。

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-456f62e08f11> in <module>
     24 
     25 np.random.seed(1)
---> 26 size_10=calc_sample_mean(size=10,n_trial=10000)
     27 size_10_df=pd.DataFrame({
     28     "sample_mean":size_10,

<ipython-input-18-456f62e08f11> in calc_sample_mean(size, n_trial)
     17     sample_mean_array=np.zeros(n_trial)
     18     for i in range(0,n_trial):
---> 19         sample=population.rvs(size==size)
     20         sample_mean_array[i]=sp.mean(sample)
     21     return(sample_mean_array)

~\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in rvs(self, size, random_state)
    466         kwds = self.kwds.copy()
    467         kwds.update({'size': size, 'random_state': random_state})
--> 468         return self.dist.rvs(*self.args, **kwds)
    469 
    470     def sf(self, x):

~\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in rvs(self, *args, **kwds)
    950         # by _rvs().
    951         self._size = size
--> 952         vals = self._rvs(*args)
    953 
    954         vals = vals * scale + loc

~\Anaconda3\envs\Python3.7\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_continuous_distns.py in _rvs(self)
    215     """
    216     def _rvs(self):
--> 217         return self._random_state.standard_normal(self._size)
    218 
    219     def _pdf(self, x):

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.standard_normal()

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.cont0_array()

TypeError: an integer is required
```

このエラーについて調べるもopen関数の例しかなく、よくわかりません

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージにも書かれているこの行における関数の引数が間違っていそうです。

```
sample=population.rvs(size==size)
```

変数 `population` の定義が無いので `rvs()` が何なのか正確には分かりませんが（おそらく[これ](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs.html)？）オプショナル引数 `size` を指定するのであれば `size=size` と書くべきです。`size==size` だと比較になってしまい、この場合 `True` にしかなりません。